# Meaning and usage of vintage

Tags: word-usage

I often trad the word "vintage" but I don't know if it used in everyday language? 
Does it apply mainly to wines?

Answer (score 1):

As a noun, yes, it mainly refers to a good quality wine or to the specific year that a wine was made.

As an adjective, it can be used to describe an old car/aircraft/watch that is still in a good condition and shows the best and most typical characteristics of its kind. Vintage things are old-fashioned, but of high quality and lasting value.

Comment: In Britain, a 'vintage' car is one made between 1919 and 1930. A 'veteran' car is older; strictly defined it is one made before 1905, but this is sometimes stretched to before 1919.